# Double on Android. Strange rounding

Tags: android, double

On Android (Nexus One 2.3.7) I receive a line from socket "0 54.95325 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0"
Then I do following:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols sym = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
sym.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("");
form.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);              

String[] tokens = null;
String[] tempData = null;
tring[] windData = null;

tokens = line.split(";");
tempData = tokens[0].trim().split("\\s"); // OR " ";
windData = tokens[1].trim().split("\\s");  

for (int i = 0; i < currentTemp.length; i++)
    currentTemp[i] = form.parse(tempData[i]).doubleValue();

Log.d("CurrentTemp0: ", currentTemp[0]+"");
Log.d("CurrentTemp1: ", currentTemp[1]+"");
```

And in log I see: CurrentTemp1: ( 5554): 54.0.
Why 54.0?? It's must be 54.95325.

I dont know what to think...

Here is log from another Nexus One (2.3.5):

```
D/Socket:(9855): 73,8189241834073 73,8812582487619 73,5927450599115 73,0117432312163 ; 3,70756496056335 3,68967387857366 4,05669701334867 3,87624105013732 
D/CurrentTemp0:(9855): 73.8189241834073
D/CurrentTemp1:(9855): 73.8812582487619
D/CurrentTemp2:(9855): 73.5927450599115
D/CurrentTemp3:(9855): 73.0117432312163
```

Kind of a mystery...

Comment: Could it be that the values are being rounded during the calculations in a way that you do not expect? In the page I've attached, it shows that the `DecimalFormat` class in java uses half-even rounding.   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is empty that could be the reason, if you want all values after dot, you need specify

```
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("###.#####");
```

Here is link for [possible decimal formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Comment: I'll try. But why another device working correctly? (See updated 1st post)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is wrong with DecimalFormat, but I changed it with Double and it's working great:

```
String buf = tempData[i].replace(",", ".");
currentTemp[i] = Double.parseDouble(buf);
```